# Spring Batch CouchBase bulk read opration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring batch and and my database is Couchbase. Is there any way to read documents from Couchbase in batch or in bulk mode?

Comment: There is no batch kv api for couchbase - because it's faster to read multiple documents individually with the kv api (every request for a document will be sent to the node holding that document).  
Mulitiple documents can be read using the query api, but this will be slower as the documents must be transfered from the node holding the document to the node processing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Spring batch extensions project
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/pull/5/commits

Comment: Thanks @johnnyutts ,Any idea when that extension will be released ?